# Circular dependency in Wt::Dbo

Tags: c++, wt, wt-dbo

Wt recommends to use forward declarations to avoid circular dependencies.

```
// Settings.h
#include <Wt/Dbo/Dbo.h>
#include <string>

class User; // Forward declaration of User Wt::Dbo object

class Settings 
{
public:
  Wt::Dbo::ptr<User> user;

  template<class Action>
  void persist(Action& a)
  {
    Wt::Dbo::belongsTo(a, user);
  }
};
```

```
// User.h
#include <Wt/Dbo/Dbo.h>
#include <string>

#include "Settings.h"

class User
{
public:
  Wt::Dbo::weak_ptr<Settings> settings;

  template<class Action>
  void persist(Action& a)
  {
    Wt::Dbo::hasOne(a, settings);
  }
};
```

However, when I use this `Settings` class in another cpp file, the program doesn't compile:

```
// test.cpp
#include "Settings.h"
```

> error: C2079: 'dummy' uses undefined class 'User'

**Possible solutions (which I do not like)**

1. A solution is to include in `User.h` in every cpp file that includes `Settings.h`, i.e.:

   ```
   // test.cpp
   #include "User.h"
   #include "Settings.h"
   ```

   I do not prefer this solution, because I have to remember to include `User.h` every time I include `Settings.h`.
2. Another solution is to use the non-recommended `DBO_EXTERN_TEMPLATES` macro, i.e.

   ```
   // Settings.h
   ...
   class Settings
   {
   public:
      ....
   };

   DBO_EXTERN_TEMPLATES(Settings)
   ```

   I do not prefer this solution as this macro is not recommend, nor documented. `DBO_EXTERN_TEMPLATES` doesn't work with all compilers.

**Question**

a. What is the best/preferred methodology to overcome circular dependencies between `Wt::Dbo` objects avoiding the mentioned `undefined class` error?

b. <strike>Why does solution 1. works?</strike>

I created a new (general - not `Wt::Dbo` specific) question (with an MCVE), to clarify the specific situation: [When are member functions of a templated class instantiated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59435038/when-are-member-functions-of-a-templated-class-instantiated)

**References**

- DBO_EXTERN_TEMPLATES: https://www.mail-archive.com/witty-interest@lists.sourceforge.net/msg06963.html
- Wt::Dbo and circular depencies: https://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/boards/2/topics/290?r=292
- The given example is based on the `Wt::Dbo` tutorial: https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/tutorial/dbo.html#_em_one_to_one_em_relations, but I want to place the different classes into different header files.

Comment: Does `User` depend on `Settings`?

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Yes, it does. I extended the example to clarify this.

Comment: You can have user include setting, or vice versa. Just not both.

Comment: @ChrisMM, Yes, I know (and reflected it in my updated question). I wonder how the Wt::Dbo library expects its user to handle such circular dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer of ChrisMM, another solution is to forward declare your class at the top of its header file:

Settings.h:

```
// include guard
class Settings;
#include "User.h"

class Settings { ... };
```

Users.h:

```
// include guard
class User;
#include "Settings.h"

class User { ... };
```

The advantage of this approach is that you only have to forward declare the class in its own header file and are allowed to just include the file in any other (header) file that need it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with `Wt::Dbo`, but I don't believe the issue is specific with it. It is more a general C++ class design issue, which you need to work around/with; it is actually rather common in C++ projects.

For the "best/preferred method," that really is a matter of opinion. In your case, you can actually have both `User.h` and `Settings.h` include each other, if you still have the forward declarations.

For example, in `Settings.h`:

```
// include guard
class User;
#include "User.h"

class Settings { ... };
```

Then in `User.h`, you can do:

```
// include guard
class Settings;
#include "Settings.h"

class User { ... };
```

I know this seems odd, but it is a way to ensure you don't have to include both headers all the time. Alternatively, you just do that in one header, and ensure that is the one you always include.

In general, my preferred way is, in header files, only include what is absolute needed in the header, and forward declare the rest. In the source files, I then include the headers which are actually needed. The reason for this is because then, if I need to change one header file, I don't have to recompile all the source files which included that header; it improves the performance of the compilation process.

As for your question as to why solution 1 works, it's because of how you are including the files. In that specific example, you don't even need to include `Settings.h` in the source file, because `User.h` already does this. But let's look at how it looks once the pre-processor is done with it.

When you include `User.h`, it first includes `Settings.h`. An include basically copies the contents into the current file where the include occurred. So, effectively, your `User.h` would look something like this:

```
// User.h
#include <Wt/Dbo/Dbo.h> // contents from this would be here
#include <string> // contents from this would be here

// Settings.h
#include <Wt/Dbo/Dbo.h> // contents NOT included, due to previous include and include guards
#include <string> // same as above

class User; // Forward declaration of User Wt::Dbo object

class Settings 
{
public:
  Wt::Dbo::ptr<User> user;

  template<class Action>
  void persist(Action& a)
  {
    Wt::Dbo::belongsTo(a, user);
  }
};

class User
{
public:
  Wt::Dbo::weak_ptr<Settings> settings;

  template<class Action>
  void persist(Action& a)
  {
    Wt::Dbo::hasOne(a, settings);
  }
};
```

What you can see now, is that when the `Settings` class is being defined, the `User` is already forward declared and can be used by the `Settings` class. When `User` is then defined, it has the full definition of `Settings` to work with. In your `test.cpp` file now, both `Settings` and `User` are fully defined, and hence can be used.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I, too, only try to include necessary files in header files, but as every file that includes `Settings.h` has to include `User.h`, I don't think any recompilation is avoided by not including `User.h` in `Settings.h`, is it?

Comment: I know the contents expands to what you have shown, but I'm wondering when the definition of the `User` class is used (instead of the forward declaration) as the `User` class is only used before its definition? Is the template `Wt::Dbo::ptr<User>`  instantiated at the end of the file?

Comment: Is your solution an ill-formed program according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/59435158/7621674?

Comment: The `User` class is not actually used before it's definition; it just looks like it is. `Wt::Dbo::ptr` is presumably a wrapper around a pointer, and pointers do not need the full definition of a class, until it is instantiated / used. Since you aren't actually instantiating a `User` object, or calling any of its functions in the `Settings` class, then it is perfect fine, and is still well formed.