# When are member functions of a templated class instantiated?

Tags: c++, templates, class-template

Consider the following example:

```
template<typename T>
class Base
{
public:
  inline void fooBase ()
  {
    T t; // The following error only occurs when class ABC is not defined at the end of the file: "error: t uses undefined class ABC"
  }
protected:
};

class ABC;
class DEF;

class Derived : public Base<ABC>
{
public:
  void fooDerived ()
  {
    DEF def; // error: def uses undefined class DEF
  }
};

Derived derived;
void foo ()
{
  derived.fooBase ();
}

class ABC {};
class DEF {};
```

**Question(s)**

1. Why is the compiler happy with class `ABC` only defined at the end of the file?
2. Why is the definition not needed when declaring `Derived`, nor when declaring the global `foo` function?
3. When are member functions of a templated class instantiated? Even when the function is made explicit inline, the function seems to be instantiated (at the end of the file) after the function is called in `foo ()`.
4. Is this behaviour standard C++? If so, does it depends on the C++ version used?

Note that `fooDerived` generates an error as expected: the class should be (fully) defined before it is used.

*Note that it is not necessary to answer all the questions separately, as they are rather different formulations of the same question.*

**Tested environment:**

- MSVC (but I'm interested in cross platform compliance.)
- It seems to work (except for `DEF def;` as expected) on the three main compilers (GCC, CLang AND MSVC): https://godbolt.org/z/z_c7mc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When are member functions of a templated class instantiated?

The **declaration** of a class template specialization's member function is instantiated along with the class specialization, but the **definition** is only instantiated when needed. Usually when the member function is called. So long as nothing uses the member function, the definition may go un-instantiated.

Your example calls the member function, so the definition must be instantiated.

There may however be multiple points of instantiation for a member function of a specialization. One is immediately before being used, but an additional one (that is always added) is at the end of the translation unit

> **[temp.point]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.point#8) A specialization for a function template, a member function
>   template, or **of a member function or static data member of a class
>   template may have multiple points of instantiations within a
>   translation unit, and in addition to the points of instantiation
>   described above, for any such specialization that has a point of
>   instantiation within the translation unit, the end of the translation
>   unit is also considered a point of instantiation**. A specialization for
>   a class template has at most one point of instantiation within a
>   translation unit. A specialization for any template may have points of
>   instantiation in multiple translation units. **If two different points
>   of instantiation give a template specialization different meanings
>   according to the one-definition rule, the program is ill-formed, no
>   diagnostic required.**

Which brings me to the next point,`fooBase` has two points of instantiations in the translation unit you show. In one `ABC` is incomplete, while in the other it has been completed. Under the paragraph above, your program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. A compiler can be silent about the violation, all the while emitting some code the *seems* to work. But that does not make the program valid. If the standard is updated in the future to require a diagnostic in this case, the illegal code will fail to build. It may even fail now if compilers wish to diagnose it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the code will not be ill-formed when `foo()` is defined after class `ABC`, i.e. at the end of the file?

Comment: @m7913d - You understood correctly, yes. If `ABC` is completed before `foo`, the program will be well-formed.

Comment: So, the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59432168/7621674) (last code blob) is ill-formed too?

Comment: @m7913d - It looks okay at a glance. Smart pointer types are often written to handle incomplete types correctly. The key is for the type to be complete before any member function that requires a complete type is defined. In the snippet you show, I don't believe there is a problem. A `wek_ptr` usually doesn't need a complete object type at all, and nothing else in the short snippet is instantiated or uses `User` before its completion.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It is only tricky as the compiler does not have to include an error message.